# Searching for a value and appending if a value exists

Tags: python, file, list, search, append

Hi i am running a search through a csv file in python 2.7 but im encountering an error in the searching. The file im searching is about 10000 entries long and of the form and here is a sample from the file. Some Daysworkedthismonth contain no values.

```
Name,Year Commenced,DaysWorkedthismonth
John,1990,4
Jane,1996,3
Josh,1990,
Jess,1990,2
```

What I am trying to do is search row by row through the file and match a specific value. for the file im searching  for the values that match 1990 and appending that row to a list. I wish to search the file and only append the row to a list if it also contains a value in another colummn.

I.e I want to search the file example for say 1990 but only append the row to the file if there is a value in the daysworkedthismonth. So when I search for 1990 and has a value in the daysworkedthismonth colummn the strings appended to the row should only be

```
John,1990,4
Jess,1990,2
```

Is there anyway to conduct such a search??

So far I've tried but I have a feeling this is wrong

```
for row in a_csv:
 existing=  (for row in a_csv if '1990' in row)
 print existing
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have some existing code, please edit it into your answer. If not, you should have a look at Python's `csv` module.

Comment: @Marius I have added the code I have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of fields in a row by using [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the row:

```
with open('csvFile', 'r') as a_csv:
    for row in a_csv:
        elems = row.split(',')
        if len(elems) == 3 and elems[1] == '1990': 
            print row
```

Comment: Hi, this works fine for a variable. However if I try and implement this with a list it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to use this somehow with a list??

Comment: Are you talking about the `elems` variable, or `row`?  Do you want to print out a row as a list?

Comment: Ummm. when the file reads it is placed in a list. Im trying to say if 1990 exists and row[2](daysworked) is not empty then print the row. Does that make sense??

Comment: Is your list named `a_csv`?

Comment: I edited my answer to include how I open files.  Just change `csvFile` to the actual file name.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to search if list index[2] in this case is not empty??

Comment: Yes everyhting is fine